# Google Tag Manager invalid template

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-tag-manager

When I try to publish the google tag it says it is an invalid template, it is a white countdown clock with a transparent background.

```
<iframe src="http://free.timeanddate.com/countdown/i57ntw7m/n198/cf11/cm0/cu4/ct0/cs0/ca0/co0/cr0/ss0/cacfff/cpc000/pcfff/tcfff/fs100/szw320/szh135/iso2016-11-18T00:00:00" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" width="275" height="19"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

GTM does not consider "allowTransparency" to be a valid attribute. If you remove it you should be able publish your tag as custom HTML.